# React Native - lifetime of an array element

Tags: react-native

It is possible to remove an array element after 'X' time?

I'm creating an APP that searches for beacons and inserts the UUID of the beacon in an array. But after 10 or 15 min I want to discard that element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle couple of app delegate events in which you can manage the entries in your array. If you app is running in foreground continuously you can use the setTimeout function of JS to do it at regular interval of time. You also need to do the same on your app launch and when you app returns to foreground from background mode.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but could you make a simple example with the setTimeout function? I'm kind a noob at programming, and a example is simpler to understand.